# Unable to render content of custom page from custom controller in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

There are custom page like:

```
# app/admin/csv/bar_csv.rb
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'bar_csv' do
  content do
     ...
  end
end
```

and custom controller like:

```
# app/admin/bar/bar.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Bar do
  controller do
    def index
      ...
      # I expect render content of bar_csv
      render 'admin/bar_csv'
    end
  end
end
```

I expect to render content of `bar_csv` as custom controller when I access `admin/bars`. But I encountered `Template is missing`.
I tried `render 'admin/bar_csv/index'`, `render 'bar_csv/index'`, `render 'admin/bar_csv'` and `render 'bar_csv'` as well

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Please post the filenames and path of your snipets.

Comment: Edited to add path and file name in my snippets

Comment: Try `render partial: /admin/csv/bar_csv` or `render partial: /csv/bar_csv`

Comment: I tried both. But it didn't work.

Error:
`
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial admin/csv/_bar_csv with {:locale=>[:ja], :formats =>[:csv], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :coffee, :slim, :jbuilder, :md, :markdown]}. 
`